# Angular Material: Using *ngIf inside a table

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-material-5, angular-material-6

I have a `mat-table` in which I pass some data and build out the table using Angular Material's table component. For some reason when I use `*ngif="{{Participant,status != 1}}"` to show/hide a button, it errors.

Here is my code for the `td` cell:

```html
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let Participant">
  <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="participantStatusMenu" class="participantStatusBtn">
    <span>
      {{Participant.status | participantStatus}}
      <fa-icon [icon]="['fas', 'angle-down']" size="lg"></fa-icon>
    </span>
  </button>
  <mat-menu #participantStatusMenu="matMenu" class="participantStatusMenu">
    <button *ngIf="{{Participant.status != 1}}" mat-menu-item>{{1 | participantStatus}}</button>
    <button mat-menu-item>{{2 | participantStatus}}</button>
    <button mat-menu-item>{{3 | participantStatus}}</button>
  </mat-menu>
</td>
```

Comment: Next time, please add the error itself. Otherwise, we won't be able to help you debug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove the annotation {{}} when you are using *ngIf

```
 <button *ngIf="Participant.status !== '1'" mat-menu-item>{{1 | participantStatus}}</button>
```